# How to update a column with a single button in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, sql, forms, angularjs, sql-update

I have an `Unapproved` button on my list page. As I'm a complete rookie with angular, I don't really see how to pull out the id of the given post and update the column in db that makes sure it becomes `approved`. Can you please show me how to do that? The code goes smthn like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <button ng-click="approved()" class="unapproved" ng-if="article.current_revision.approved == false" ng-model="article.current_revision.approved">Unapproved</button>
</form>
```

What should I put in my controller to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like this where your controller has the approved fn which accepts the id.

```
ng-click="approved(article.id)"
```

Did I correctly understand your question?  If not, please elaborate.  A jsFiddle always helps tremendously too.